# Magento not responding to payment gateway notifications fast enough or at all?

Tags: magento

Some of our customers are getting to the confirmation of payment step in purchasing from our Magento store, and then they are getting a timeout error, where the SagePay payment gateway is trying to contact our server to tell it that a payment was successful (or not…) but it cannot contact our server, or cannot get a response from our server in a timely manner, and then the payment/order is being cancelled.

I've raised this question to my hosting company, but all they told me was:

"This is down to the way the software is configured on your server"

This is currently a Magento 1.4.0.1 standard installation as far as payment gateways are concerned. What on earth could this statement mean?

Is there some configuration that I need to do to make Magento listen to these requests and respond properly?

Comment: Your hosting plan has you using a server that can't keep up during a process that has critical timing issues, or is misconfigured, or is on a network segment that is causing delays in the request/response negotiations required for payment processing to work. Payment and shipping modules will suffer timeout issues if the server is loaded to the point that it cannot pay attention to the responses from the remote servers or fails to receive them in a timely manner.

Answer (score 1):

Have you logged into http://www.sagepay.com/system_monitor to check their network? Also is your SSL up to date?

Update to the latest version of Magento community edition which is `ver 1.6.2.0 - Added January 11, 2012` from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download

If sagepay is connected with a plugin check with the plugin author if it's a default gateway available from magento check their bug reports for your version.

I would also ask sagepay to tell you what is the exact server header response they are getting

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have discussed with SagePay, and have had them send me logs from their servers regarding specific failed transactions. It shows that their systems are trying repeatedly to connect to my server, and not getting a reply.

We are in the process of upgrading to the latest version of Magento.

I haven't yet contacted the sagepay plugin vendor, but may do if the upgrade doesn't fix the issues.

Comment: Are your customers able to submit their credit card details? Is that information being posted successfully to sage pay servers? And is it only the server / gateway response that's failing?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. We are seeing failed payments in our sagepay transaction list, and the upshot of investigating this is that the server seems to not be responding in a timely manner. Our server is very powerful and runs our magento site very quickly, we have no speed issues that we are aware of. Our server provider hinted that there could be something in the settings of the way the magento installation is setup causing this issue, but that's as far as that went... no further clues.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with Google Checkout, where Magento wasn't able to process the request fast enough to conform to Google's limits.  The answer is upgraded to the best version, optimizing your site where ever you can (nginx proxy passing, setting proper image caching, make sure DB is optimized), and unfortunately if it comes to it getting faster hardware.  Good luck!